# Rails using wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, apple-m1

I am on a Mac M1, I installed ruby with rosetta and it worked fine for a long time. I had to reinstall Brew because of other reason and took the opportunity to install it just in ARM.
I installed ruby 3.1.2 to run an external proyect using rbenv but rails doesen't recognize it.

When I run rbenv:

```
> rbenv version

3.1.2 (set by /Users/vicente/.rbenv/version)
```

If I run ruby:

```
> ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]
```

But when I run rails:

```
> rails s
Ignoring nokogiri-1.13.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.13.8
Ignoring nokogiri-1.13.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.13.8
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0
Ignoring racc-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.5.2
.... It repeats similar warnings A LOT ...

Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2
```

This also fails with new proyects, if I run `rails new app` it shows the same message

When I run rails outside of the proyect it throws the same warnings and this:

```
> rails

Rails 7 requires Ruby 2.7.0 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

Please upgrade to Ruby 2.7.0 or newer to continue.
```

I already tried with `sudo gem pristine — all` and reinstalling rails

EDIT:

If I run which rails:

```
> which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
```

Also, when I run bundle install in the proyect folder it seems to work fine:

```
> bundle install
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
... Bunch of other gems ...
Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 105 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

EDIT 2:

I have ran `rbenv rehash` and it didn´t change

Comment: Did you install the `rails` gem under the current active rbenv version? The command `which rails` will tell you where the shell is loading the `rails` command from. It should be coming from the rbenv shims folder for your current active Ruby version. Please add the output of `which rails` to your quesion.

Comment: Did you try to simply run `bundle install` in the application folder? What did it return?

Answer (score 1):

Create a .ruby-version file with the version you need:
Example:

.ruby-version

```
3.1.2
```

also make sure that your default version matches the version you specified.

And try to make `gem install rails`

Comment: This didn´t work. I tried with my .ruby-version as `3.1.2` and `ruby-3.1.2`. Uninstalled and installed again with both. But I still throws the same error

Comment: Try use `rbenv rehash`.

Comment: Also tried that and didn´t work :(

Comment: May  be `rbenv global 3.1.2`